# google-play-services.jar doesn't include com.google.android.gms.ads

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I have added the google-play-service (downloaded with SDK Manager) project to eclipse and then added the lib in my project. But when I try to use com.google.android.gms.ads it tells me it can't be resolved. So I checked a bit closer on the jar and notice that gms.ads is not in there. [image]

Do I have the wrong Jar, or have I imported it wrong?

Comment: YOu added the jar to libs folder?

Comment: I think you have old jar becz new jar have manly two package ads and android.gms

Comment: @RaghunandanEverything is added, I can find the other packs, but not ads.

Comment: @Haresh But I downloaded from the SDK-manager, can't find any newer there...